# How to restore folder structure from a minified/bundled up sencha file esm-all on Sencha 4.2?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm new to sencha, and I'm working on a project that has the following scenario:

I have an esm-all.js big file (210k+ lines), and from what I understood, the whole framework and the application behaviour code is bundled up in this big file.
I don't have any other project with folder structure and javascript modules separated in different files in order to start developing and debugging the current features of the application.

So I was wondering how should I procede on that situation, should I try to extract aplication code from that big file and separate them onto different files?
Is that modularization even possible?

Another person on the project has tried doing the modularization but he said was not possible in Sencha 4.2. He also said it was not possible to import files.

If it's possible, does anyone have a good article on that?
And about the scenario, does anyone have any tips how could I procede?

I have researched a lot, and didn't find any articles besides on how to do simple things in Sencha 4.2.

It would be really helpful to get the file and folder structure back, I think for sencha [would be](https://www.sencha.com/blog/a-step-by-step-guide-to-an-extjs-tutorial-for-beginners/):

APP_FOLDER

- ModelView
- Model
- Store
- View
- Utils
  app.js

Thank you.

Comment: This `esm-all.js` is a generated file that was created during a build process probably made with Sencha Cmd. You need the original source code split to several smaller JS files, I am not aware of a method to extract these from the generated build output.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that. Unfortunately the project with folder structure is not available. So I'll have to extract that application code from there. And I think I already have the answers I need. The modularization is possible on Sencha v4, in fact it's the normal way of working with it. And there is no need for "importing", because sencha framework already takes care of it through the wiring of controllers, views, and models. The real work now it's to extract the controllers, views and models, understand them and make it work. Thank you.